# indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. && Attempted to access f(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab coming from c++ and trying to do 2d convolution. I have done dry run but nothing seems to go wrong but i dont know why this coming
My simple logic if value is lesser equal to zero then place zero. I am using this expression for solving that problem

[image]

i am facing 2 errors at

1)at f(q,p)=zeros(q,p);

2) at  output_args(x,y)=output_args(x,y) + (W(s, t)* f(q,p));

```
function output_args = convo(img,k )
 //skipped the portion of code---

z=s;i=t;
    for x=1:row
        for y=1:col
           for s=s:a+2
              % disp(s);
               for t= t:b+2
                   q=z-s;
                   p=i-t;
                   if q<=0
                       if p <=0
                           f(q,p)=0; %// trying to place zero at index so help needed which is 1st error i have said
                       end
                   end
           %        disp(f(q,p));
                   output_args(x,y)=output_args(x,y) + (W(s, t)* f(q,p));  %//2nd error is comin (as i have told you above.

               end
           end
     w=w+1;   
        end
        z=z+1;
    end

end
```

at console:(error occur when i apply

```
1) Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals at f(q,p)=0

2) Attempted to access f(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical.  output_args(x,y)=output_args(x,y) + (W(s, t)* f(q,p));
```

so any idea?

Comment: The message is self-explanatory, you're trying to use 0 as an index. The fix is to not do that.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is right. Matlab indices start at 1, not 0.

Comment: thats why i used if ...<=0 then place 0 in that f( , ). but cant understand why this is not so happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if q<=0
    if p <=0
        f(q,p)=0; % p and q will always be invalid!
    end
end
```

Well, that is begging for that error. In MATLAB, Indices must be greater than zero. While you can invert the if-condition to ensure that the index is positive, that will change the mending of your code.

```
if q > 0
    if p > 0
        f(q,p)=0; % p and q will always be valid.
    end
end
```

If you need to index from -5 to 5 (for example) you could instead index from 1 to 11 instead. Just remember that you subtract 6 every time you display values. Alternatively, store the "real" indices in another vector.

Comment: my second error still exists so help that is Attempted to access f(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical. at output_args(x,y)=output_args(x,y) + (W(s, t)* f(q,p));

Comment: Can you move that line into the if-condition?

Comment: my logic is disrupts now. if i remove if portion it stills states same: Attempted to access f(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical. at output_args(x,y)=output_args(x,y) + (W(s, t)* f(q,p));